# How to load the values in combobox from database

Tags: extjs, combobox

How do I populate combo box  values instead of  hard coding from the database into the store of combo box

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    title: 'Dress Types',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            displayField: "displayName",
            valueField: "displayName",
            emptyText: 'Select Type',
            store: {
                fields: ["id", "displayName"],
                data: [
                    { "id": "1", "displayName": "Kurtha" },
                    { "id": "2", "displayName": "Denim Top" },
                    { "id": "3", "displayName": "Western T shirt" },
                    { "id": "4", "displayName": "Sleeveless" }
                ]
            },
            name: 'dresses',
            margin: '15px',
            allowBlank: false,
            forceSelection: true,
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create `store` and a `model` for your data set and assign it to your combobox. Read the [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.Store.html)

Comment: @qmat if I'm using like below,

it's not working , but can you correct me??

`var store = Ext.create('Ext.ux.data.SqlStore', {`
    `storeId: "dresstore",`
   `sql: "SELECT dresstype FROM dresstable"`
`});`

Comment: both solutions below are good for your. Take a look at them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below code.

```
 Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    valueField: "displayName",
    emptyText: 'Select Type',
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ["id", "displayName"],
        proxy: {
            url: 'data1.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    }),
    name: 'dresses',
    margin: '15px',
    allowBlank: false,
    forceSelection: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

I assumed my service returing data like below

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": "1",
    "displayName": "Kurtha"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "displayName": "Denim Top"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "displayName": "Western T shirt"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "displayName": "Sleeveless"
}]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are ways by which you can get this. You need to create one store in your js from your input data and then assign it to the comboBox.

Given example

```
var combstore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: [{
                name: 'value',
                mapping: "ITEMID",
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'name',
                mapping: "TITLE",
                type: 'string'
            }],
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                type: 'ajax',
                actionMethods: {
                    read: "POST"
                },
                url: Your URL,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                },
                autoLoad: true
            })
        });
```

Now in your comboBox you can call this `combstore` to your `store`.
`store :combstore`

In the variable combostore we are creating one data store by using `Ext.data.Store` and placing values in field. Then in proxy method calling url and mapping the values from field.
Read the doc for better understanding [Doc](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.Store.html)